# Is aviation exhaust the culprit for climate change?

Tags: atmospheric-science, weather, climate-science

The ongoing climate change is the biggest threat to the human civilization. 
The recent 4-year drought in California, other droughts and floods in different parts of the world are posing serious threat to the mankind. Thousands of people are losing lives or livelihood on regular basis.
Scientists believe global warming as the main cause for climate change. But I believe, the biggest culprit for climate change is - aviation exhaust 
(i.e. exhaust made by jet airplanes). The exhaust contain CO2 + water vapor. Water vapor gets converted into 
tiny ice crystals. These water crystals floating in upper atmosphere reflect the sun rays away from the earth (back to the empty space) in the same way 
the cirrus clouds do. If the skies were clear, when the sun rays in rather pristine form falls on the ground and ocean, it creates the differential of 
pressure and temperature to create conducive conditions for precipitation. Absence of a strong sunlight is what preventing timely rains. 
And this is what probably damaging the world weather systems. Can blockage of a tiny fraction of the sunlight cause big changes in weather?

Comment: have you made any estimate of how much water vapor and CO2 is released by airplanes as compared with other sources. My guess is that the contribution by airplanes will be negligible.

Comment: No CO2 under scanner, consider only the water vapor. Water vapor at 10000 - 40,000 feet  in the atmosphere gets converted into tiny ice crystals as temperature goes into minus.  It can only reach there by jet exhaust I guess.

Comment: This question is more like a discussion on a very important current topic. I am not entirely familiar with SE's format, but I think it is quite relevant having a discussion to solve  complex problems we face. Enlightened moderators agree to this?

Answer (score 2):

It is estimated that aviation is responsible for 12% of transport CO2 emissions worldwide at present (2015 data), with an additional effect due to NO2 and induced O3. Transport itself contributes just over a quarter of all CO2 emissions, with the other main contributions from power (electricity) production, industry, commercial and residential sources, and agriculture. Overall, aviation is estimated to be responsible for just over 3% of CO2 emissions from all sources. Carbon dioxide is estimated to be responsible for approximately 80% of global warming, with other trace gases, particularly CH4 (which has a global warming potential 3.7 times greater than that of CO2) making up the other 20%. Aviation can therefore be estimated to be responsible for around 2.5% of all global warming, based upon our current data and analyses.

Note that the output of water vapour from aircraft would be insignificant compared to the 69% of the Earth's surface that is covered in water. A buildup of ice crystals in the atmosphere would have a (very) slight cooling effect by reflecting UV light, which could reasonably be ignored.

Also note that it is understood that there is no single cause or *culprit* for climate change. The primary cause is understood to be the anthropogenic production of CO2, but there are many other known contributors, both anthropogenic and otherwise, and they are invariably interrelated.

Comment: The water vapor can't go to 40,000 feet by natural causes. This is a man induced change to upper troposphere and it must be taken into account as one of the causes for climate change.

Comment: Clouds can in fact reach altitudes of over 18,000 metres (or approximately 60,000 feet) in the tropics. The tropopause is essentially defined by these conditions. Standard cruising altitude for a commercial passenger plane is about 10,700 metres (35,000 feet) and most have a ceiling of around 13,700 (45,000 feet).

Comment: Ok, so clouds can ascend to that height, thanks for enlightening me. But still why should we not take into account the additional  pouring of water vapor into the atmosphere by jetliners? Professor Carleton and his team has done some research in this regard and has published a report in International Journal of Climatology:  
http://phys.org/news/2015-06-jet-contrails-affect-surface-temperatures.html#nRlv